# how to logout and cannot properly logout with php?

Tags: php, session-cookies, logout

Here the go where user is log in. I cannot seem to be able to logout when I log in with 'remember me' not active...

```
while($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $passwordDB = $user['mypassword'];
        $email = $user['email_address'];
        $userid = $user['user_id'];
    }

 if ($remember_me == "true"){ // Create a Cookie if remember_me is active
      $expire = time()+60*60*24; // Valid for only 1 day
      setcookie("cookie_username", $username, $expire, "/");
      setcookie("cookie_email", $email, $expire, "/");
      setcookie("cookie_userid", $userid, $expire, "/");

     } else if ($remember_me == "false") { // Only create a session if remember_me is not active
                session_start(); // cannot logout if i put it here
                $_SESSION['session_userid'] = $userid;
                $_SESSION['session_username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['session_email'] = $email;

            }
```

My php logout code

```
<?php

require_once 'mydatabase.php';

 $_SESSION = array();

 if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {

 $params = session_get_cookie_params();
 setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 86400,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );

 }

 ?>
```

I can properly logout when my 'remember me' checked is on.
**Issue solve:** I accidentally erase my `session_start()` at the top of my logout and forgot to put it back in.

Comment: can you post the code where you check if user is logged in? I assume you need to reset the cookie values for all fields. Use the web developer tools of your browser to see which values are set

Answer (score 0):

To kill off all the session variables you could try something akin to this

```
if( isset( $_SESSION ) ){

    $vars=array(
        'session_userid',
        'session_username',
        'session_email'
    );

    foreach( $vars as $var ){
        @unset( $_SESSION[ $var ] );
    }

    @session_unset();
    @session_destroy();
    @session_start();
    @session_regenerate_id( true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you check if user is logged in, id assume that you need to `session_start();` in your logout code as well

Use the [developer tools](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/web-development-tools/a/using-the-browser-developer-tools) to see which data the browser is currently holding.

Comment: I believe my found my mistake... wait a sec. Stupid mistake, I believe I accidentally erase my `session start()` at the start of my logout php, tys for reminding of that. It now work

Comment: feel free to accept my answer then. next time, paste all the code since very few people have magic crystal balls to see the missing pieces ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use session_start and session_destroy() like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

require_once 'mydatabase.php';

 if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {

 $params = session_get_cookie_params();
 setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 86400,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );

 }
```

Comment: maybe first delete the session cookie, then destroy the session?